# Selenium python how to use assertEqual method from unittest.TestCase "No such test method in <class 'unittest.case.TestCase'>"

Tags: python, selenium, python-unittest

I try to use assertEqual in usual class and can't call method from unittest.TestCase

```
    class MyPages(unittest.TestCase):

        @classmethod
        def setUpClass(cls):
            basetest.BaseTest().open_browser('firefox')
            basetest.BaseTest().login()


        def testCreateFolder(self):
            print "111111111"

        def testCreateFolder1(self):
            print "222222222"

        @classmethod
        def tearDownClass(cls):
            basetest.BaseTest().close_browser()
```

And in my BaseTest I want to make login with text assert.

```
    class BaseTest():

        def open_browser(self, browser):
            self.driver = config.browser[browser]
            global driver
            driver = self.driver
            driver.get(config.url)


        def login(self):
            # Go to authorisation page
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(link.header["Login_button"]).click()
            # Get text from LOGIN label and assert it with expected text
            login_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(link.author_popup["Login_label"])
            login_text.get_attribute("text")
            print login_text.text
            unittest.TestCase().assertEqual(1, 1, "helllllllo")
            unittest.TestCase().assertEqual(login_text.text, text.author_popup["Login"],
                                "Wrong label on log in auth popup. Expected text:")
```

As a result I have the following:

```
    Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\python\PD_Tests\pages\my_pages.py", line 17, in setUpClass
        basetest.BaseTest().login()
      File "D:\python\PD_Tests\tests\basetest.py", line 25, in login
        unittest.TestCase().assertEqual(1, 1, "helllllllo")
      File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 191, in __init__
        (self.__class__, methodName))
    ValueError: no such test method in <class 'unittest.case.TestCase'>: runTest
```

Can I use assertEqual method in my method if my class is not unittest.TestCase?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a way to do what you want, but it's a little bit of a hack.

The constructor for the `TestCase` class takes a method name as a parameter, and this parameter has the default value `"runTest"`.  The docstring for this constructor reads as follows:

> Create an instance of the class that will use the named test method when executed. Raises a ValueError if the instance does not have a method with the specified name.

Hopefully this should explain the error message you are seeing.

If you want to create a `TestCase` just to use the assert methods, you can pass in the name of some other method instead, such as `__str__`.  That will get you past the checking done in the constructor:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from unittest import TestCase
>>> t = TestCase("__str__")
>>> t.assertEqual(3, 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 511, in assertEqual
    assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 504, in _baseAssertEqual
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: 3 != 5
>>> t.assertEqual(3, 3)
>>>
```

As long as you don't try to run your TestCase, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Right now i just use "if" instead of assertEqual. The only problem is that if I will have not equal text in IF my project will run next steps and assert will stop tests. But right now it's ok for me. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a special reason **not** to subclass `BaseTest` from `unittest.TestCase`?

My solution would have been to have a `SeleniumTestcase` class, which inherits from `unittest.TestCase` and provides the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods.  Just make sure your `config` is known when your `SeleniumTestcase` instance is created.